# How to make 150% scaled Qt6 app not look pixelated?

Tags: c++, qt, highdpi

I'm trying to add support for High DPI scaling to my Qt6 application. For this I added an `@2x` set of icons, which are used when scale factor is 200%. But platforms like Windows also have intermediate scale factors like 150%, and rounding up or down via `Qt::HighDpiScaleFactorRoundingPolicy` would yield too large or too small GUI.

Apparently, Qt doesn't support icon sets like `@1.5x`, so it has to use the `@2x` set downscaled. But for some reason the downscaling results in a *very* pixelated image, as if it was nearest-neighbor interpolated. See the screenshot of a run with `QT_SCALE_FACTOR=1.5` environment variable:

[image]

The code that resulted in this is here:

```
#include <QCheckBox>
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    QCheckBox cb("Check me");
    cb.setChecked(true);
    cb.setStyleSheet("QCheckBox::indicator:checked { image: url(checkbox.png); }");
    cb.show();

    return app.exec();
}
```

The icons are as follows:

- `checkbox.png` [image]
- `checkbox@2x.png` [image]

My question is: how are we supposed to handle non-integral scaling factors if not by rounding them? Does Qt simply not support making them look "right"?